# what does the m parameter in XML Signatures for gnBasis characteristic-two curves represent?

Tags: elliptic-curves, xml-encryption

https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-ECParameters defines the same three characters two-field basis's that http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=107 defines:

- GN (Gaussian Normal, I guess)
- TP (Trinomial Basis)
- PP (Pentanomial Basis)

In http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=107 just Trinomial basis and pentanomial basis have parameters and they have 1 and 3 respectively. Gaussian Normal has "NULL parameters". eg. no parameters. But in https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-ECParameters it does have a parameter:

```
<element name="GnB" type="dsig11:CharTwoFieldParamsType" />

<complexType name="CharTwoFieldParamsType">
  <sequence>
    <element name="M" type="positiveInteger" />
  </sequence>
</complexType>
```

My question is...  what does this parameter represent?